# Is it possible to have one thread control two SurfaceViews?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I would like to animate two vertical timer bars controlled by the same thread.  I am trying to avoid creating a new thread for each surfaceview which is what all the tutorials I've come across teach.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes why not, Create the a util Class outside the `SurfaceView`, then in your `SurfaceView implements Runnable Interface` and in your Util Class define ArrayList , and in your `SurfaceView` add `this` to the Util Class, and i the Util Class make loop that reads the `ArrayList` an call all objects of `Runnable` in it. i hope you got it :)

Comment: Thank you.  I am new to Android development so appreciate the guidance.  I will give this a shot and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any immediate problem doing this. SurfaceView enables drawing to the Canvas without waiting for the system to draw the View hierarchy. Provided you lock the Canvas in accordance with the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html#on-surfaceview) you probably achieve your aim.